# SO_REUSEADDR Cause Server To Reuse TIME_WAIT Connection?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

As far as I know, SO_REUSEADDR allows the server to bind to an address which is in a TIME_WAIT state. But how does it effect the action of server when accepting new connection?

Suppose we are communicating between host A and server B whose listen socket is setup with SO_REUSEADDR enabled, and there is a connection C1=(A, PortA, B, ListenPort) which is now in TIME_WAIT state (from Server B's Perspective).

Now if host A tries using the same pair (A, PortA) to connect to B, will the duplicate connection C2=(A, PortA, B, ListenPort) be established even when C1 is still in TIME_WAIT? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection attempt (SYN) will be delivered to the connection in TIME_WAIT state, which will cause it to issue an RST, which will result in the client incurring a connection refusal.

Comment: So client A fails in connecting to server, other than in receiving/sending with error '10054 - connection reset by peer'?

Comment: @Steve That's what I would expect, yes.

Answer (score -1):

If both the server socket and the client socket are using SO_REUSEADDR, both sides will be able to bind to the same port they were using before and the client will be able to establish a connection to the server.

I verified this between two local sockets on a RedHat 5 server with kernel 2.6.18.

Comment: There's nothing in the question about the server rebinding.